# Invertible linear transformations between a set with infinity norm and euclidean norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $ n \geq 2$. Show that there is no invertible linear transformation between $ S^1 := \{ x:\|x\|_{\infty} = 1\}$ and $S^2 := \{ x : \|x\|_2 =1\} $ as subsets of $( \mathbb{C}^n, \|.\|_{\infty}) $ and $ (\mathbb{C}^n, \|.\|_2) $ respectively.

I know that an invertible map implies it is one-one. Since we are talking about vector spaces, the map is a bijection. I am unable to come up with a contradiction that such a linear bijective map does not exist.

Comment: Hint: Consider extreme points of the convex hulls of two sets.

Comment: Do we take into consideration the points of intersection and try to contradict injectivity?

Comment: No. An extreme point of a convex set is a point that does not lie on any line segment that belongs to the set. Thus, the vertices of the cube are the extreme points of the cube, and every point on the boundary of the ball is an extreme point. A linear isomorphism takes extreme points to extreme points, and so there is no linear isomorphism that carries a cube onto a ball.